# cocos2d-x app won't update after code change

Tags: cocos2d-x, updates

So I just set up my Cocos2d-x framework on Eclipse by following this tutorial by Ray Wenderlich http://www.raywenderlich.com/11283/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-getting-started

Everything on the Xcode side of things are great, however, whenever I make any code changes and try to run them on my Android phone using Eclipse, the default Hello World scene appears even though the code has changed and the images were removed from the project. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to run the code

```
./build_native.sh
```

in your android/ folder and refresh your eclipse project before you deploy it on your android device